# A javascript regular expression to tokenize the query

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I'm stumbled up on a problem related to regular expressions that I cannot resolve.

I need to tokenize the query (split query into parts), suppose the following one as an example:

```
These are the separate query elements "These are compound composite terms"
```

What I eventually need is to have an array of 7 tokens:

```
1) These
2) are
3) the
4) separate
5) query
6) elements
7) These are compound composite term
```

The seventh token consists of several words because it was inside double quotation marks.

My question is: Is it possible to tokenize the input string accordingly to above explanations using **one regular expression**?

## Edit

I was curious about possibility of using `Regex.exec` or similar code instead of `split` while achieving the same thing, so I've did some investigation that was followed by [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334649/a-regular-expression-to-tokenize-the-query). And so as a another answer to a question a following regex can be used:

```
(?:")(?:\w+\W*)+(?:")|\w+
```

With the following one-liner usage scenario:

```
var tokens = query.match(/(?:")(?:\w+\W*)+(?:")|\w+/g);
```

Hope it will be useful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var s = 'These are the separate query elements "These are compound composite term"';

var arr = s.split(/(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)\s+/g); 
//=> ["These", "are", "the", "separate", "query", "elements", ""These are compound composite term""]
```

This regex will split on spaces if those are outside double quotes by using a lookahead to make sure there are even number of quotes after space.

Comment: But in this case, you have double quotation marks around `"These are compound composite term"`. I thought you needed no quotes.

Comment: Performance with look-arounds? Anubhava knows well that regex with look-arounds yield poorer performance than regexes without them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simpler approach to split the string and grab the substrings inside double quotation marks, and then get rid of empty array items with `clean` function:

```js
Array.prototype.clean = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == undefined || this[i] == '') {         
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};

var re = /"(.*?)"|\s/g; 
var str = 'These are the separate query elements "These are compound composite term"';
var arr = str.split(re);
alert(arr.clean());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get everything that is between one quote and the next `".*?"` or everything that is not a whitespace `\S+`:

```js
var re  = /".*?"|\S+/g,
    str = 'These are the separate query elements "These are compound composite term"',
    m,
    arr = [];

while ( m = re.exec( str ) ){
  arr.push( m[0] );
}
alert( arr.join('\n') );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\s(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

You can split by this.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/20