# A regular expression to tokenize the query

Tags: javascript, regex

This question is a fairly theoretical continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328788/a-javascript-regular-expression-to-tokenize-the-query) question.

I need to tokenize the query (split query into parts), suppose the following one as an example:

```
These are the separate query elements "This is composite term"
```

The point of a regex for the above query is to result with an array of 7 tokens:

```
1) These
2) are
3) the
4) separate
5) query
6) elements
7) These are compound composite term
```

The answers provided in previous question tend to use `split` or `for/while` loop in order to get the values, instead what I've wanted is a **one** reasonably fast call to `/.../g` i.e. global regex that would yield to an array of values.

What I've came out with was this regular expression

```
(?:")(?:\w+\W*)+(?:")|\w+
```

that can be called in this fashion:

```
var regex = /(?:")(?:\w+\W*)+(?:")|\w+/g
regex.exec(s)
```

But for some reason the global keyword doesn't work with it, and so it doesn't result with an array of all values, rather it returns one match at a time and requires iteration through whole string.

How do you make it work the above regular expression as global and make it return an array of values rather individual components of an array?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not write a proper tokenizer rather than use regex?

Comment: Well, at this point having a regex currently suffice me, not sure why would I want to write a tokenizer without using a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) instead of exec() to get all matches in an array:

```
s.match(regex)
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: regex.match is not a function

Comment: oh, sorry I was trying to call that on regex

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec` in a loop like this:

```
var re = /"[^"]+"|\w+/g; 
var str = 'These are the separate query elements "This is composite term"';
var m;
var arr = [] 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    arr.push(m[0]);
}

console.log(arr);
//=> ["These", "are", "the", "separate", "query", "elements", ""This is composite term""]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ1zM9/1)